# QGIS3 - Using QML in a python plugin on OSX - missing modules

Tags: qgis, pyqt, osx, qt

I have the following QML file I am trying to display in a python plugin

```js
import QtCharts 2.0
import QtQuick 2.0


ChartView {
  antialiasing: true
  title: "Chart Title"
  titleColor: "white"
  backgroundColor: "#404040"
  legend.labelColor: "white"

  PieSeries {
    PieSlice { label: "Slice0"; value: 70.0 }
    PieSlice { label: "Slice1"; value: 15.5 }
    PieSlice { label: "Slice2"; value: 14.5 }
  }
}
```

The python code looks like this:-

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QUrl
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDockWidget
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from qgis.core import QgsMessageLog


class lineStringGraph:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction('DAVE5', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)


    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def run(self):


        qml = '/Users/daveb/Webstorm/profileViewer/2019_version/linestringgraph/test.qml'
        view = QQuickView()
        view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
        view.setColor(QColor("#404040"))
        view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml))

        if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
            for error in view.errors():
                QgsMessageLog.logMessage(error.description())

        container = QWidget.createWindowContainer(view)

        widget = QDockWidget()
        widget.setWidget(container)
        widget.setMinimumHeight(300)

        self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, widget)
        widget.show()
        QMessageBox.information(None, 'Line String Graph', 'Should be visible')
```

The QML will not display and in the QGIS console I see:-

```
2019-10-17T19:14:26     WARNING    module "QtCharts" is not installed
2019-10-17T19:14:26     WARNING    module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

I thought QGIS3 uses QtQuick? I can understand QtCharts not being found. Any idea how to fix both of these errors on OSX